# Understanding the differences between mclapply and parLapply in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, mclapply

I've recently started using parallel techniques in R for a project and have my program working on Linux systems using [mclapply](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/html/mclapply.html) from the [parallel](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/doc/parallel.pdf) package. However, I've hit a road block with my understanding of `parLapply` for Windows.

Using `mclapply` I can set the number of cores, iterations, and pass that to an existing function in my workspace.

```
mclapply(1:8, function(z) adder(z, 100), mc.cores=4)
```

I don't seem to be able to achieve the same in windows using `parLapply`. As I understand it, I need to pass all the variables through using `clusterExport()` and pass the actual function I want to apply into the argument.

Is this correct or is there something similar to the `mclapply` function that's applicable to Windows?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The beauty of `mclapply` is that the worker processes are all created as clones of the master right at the point that `mclapply` is called, so you don't have to worry about reproducing your environment on each of the cluster workers.  Unfortunately, that isn't possible on Windows.

When using `parLapply`, you generally have to perform the following additional steps:

- Create a PSOCK cluster
- Register the cluster if desired
- Load necessary packages on the cluster workers
- Export necessary data and functions to the global environment of the cluster workers

Also, when you're done, it's good practice to shutdown the PSOCK cluster using `stopCluster`.

Here's a translation of your example to `parLapply`:

```
library(parallel)
cl <- makePSOCKcluster(4)
setDefaultCluster(cl)
adder <- function(a, b) a + b
clusterExport(NULL, c('adder'))
parLapply(NULL, 1:8, function(z) adder(z, 100))
```

If your `adder` function requires a package, you'll have to load that package on each of the workers before calling it with `parLapply`.  You can do that quite easily with `clusterEvalQ`:

```
clusterEvalQ(NULL, library(MASS))
```

Note that the `NULL` first argument to `clusterExport`, `clusterEval` and `parLapply` indicates that they should use the cluster object registered via `setDefaultCluster`.  That can be very useful if your program is using `mclapply` in many different functions, so that you don't have to pass the cluster object to every function that needs it when converting your program to use `parLapply`.

Of course, `adder` may call other functions in your global environment which call other functions, etc.  In that case, you'll have to export them as well and load any packages that they need.  Also note that if any variables that you've exported change during the course of your program, you will have to export them again in order to update them on the cluster workers.  Again, that isn't necessary with `mclapply` because it always creates/clones/forks the workers whenever it is called, making that unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for the in depth answer, that's really helped my understanding! While I know it's bad practise to call a function from a function, I have done it in this project for the sake of stopping the same repeated code all over the place. So, my follow up question would be, if its possible to pass more than one function to each of the slave machines, as not something to apply the ParLapply to, but as an arbitrary function?

Comment: @user2253047 ParLapply only executes the specified function, but you could pass it functions to execute, as in:`x <- list(list(sqrt, 2), list(exp, 3), list(log, 4)); parLapply(cl, x, function(a) do.call(a[[1]], a[-1]))`.

Comment: Thanks for a very helpful answer. I've always found mclapply annoying and slow, and good luck if you need to quit mid-execution. The code for this version is unwieldy, but it actually works great. Plus, one could easily write a wrapper for it.

Comment: I am on Windows, and I was about to give up on parallel processing until I found this post. Thank you SO MUCH for this information! Question: what function does `NULL` serve in the code?

Answer (score 6):

mclapply is simpler to use, and uses the underlying operating system fork() functionality to achieve parallelization. However, since Windows does not have fork(), it will run standard lapply instead - no parallelization.

parLapply is a different beast. It will create a cluster of processes, which could even reside on different machines on your network, and they communicate via TCP/IP in order to pass the tasks and results between each other.

The problem in your code there is that you didn't realize the first parameter to parLapply should be a "cluster" object. The simplest example of using parLapply to run on a single machine that I can think of is this:

```
library(parallel)

# Spawn child processes using fork() on the local machine
cl <- makeForkCluster(getOption("cl.cores", 2))

# Use parLapply to calculate lengths of 1000 strings
text = rep("Hello, world!", 1000)
len = parLapply(cl, text, nchar)

# Kill child processes since they are no longer needed
stopCluster(cl)
```

Using parLapply with a cluster created using makeForkCluster as above is functionally equivalent to calling mclapply. So it will also not work on Windows. :) Take a look at the other ways you can create a cluster with makeCluster and makePSOCKcluster on the documentation and check out what works best for your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would use `parLapply` for parallel computatiuons:

```
library(parallel)
##
test_func0 = function(i) {
  lfactorial(i) + q + d
}
##
x = 1:100
q=20
d= 25
##
t1=Sys.time()
##
clust <- makeCluster(4)

## clusterExport loads these objects from the specified environment into the clust object
clusterExport(clust, c("test_func0", "q", "d"), envir = environment())
a <- do.call(c, parLapply(clust, x, function(i) {
  test_func0(i)
}))
print(Sys.time()-t1)
##
stopCluster(clust)
```

Please keep in mind that `makeCluster` is much faster than `makePSOCKcluster` to create the environment cluster of variables to feed `parLapply`.