# How to convert foreach into a function?

Tags: r, foreach, correlation, r-future

I am using a foreach to calculate the correlation coefficients and p values, using the mtcars as an example ( foreach is overkill here but the dataframe I'm using has 450 obs for 3400 variables). I use combn to get rid of duplicate correlations and self-correlations.

```
combo_cars <- data.frame(t(combn(names(mtcars),2)))

library(foreach)
cars_res <-  foreach(i=1:nrow(combo_cars), .combine=rbind, .packages=c("magrittr", "dplyr"))     %dopar% {
  out2 <-  broom::tidy(cor.test(mtcars[, combo_cars[i,1]],
                                mtcars[,combo_cars[i,2]],
                                method = "spearman")) %>% 
    mutate(Var1=combo_cars[i,1], Var2=combo_cars[i,2])
}
```

I would like to convert this into a function, as I would like to try using the future package because I need to run correlations on subsections of the original dataframe and its more efficient them running in parallel. When trying to devise a function that replicates the above, I can use:

```
car_res2 <- data.frame(t(combn(names(mtcars), 2, function(x)  
  cor.test(mtcars[[x[1]]],
           mtcars[[x[2]]], method="spearman"), simplify=TRUE)))
```

Ultimately I would like to be able to have four futures running in parallel, each computing the above on a different fraction of the dataset.

However, the car_res2 output has 8 columns instead of 7 (the second one is completely empty). I had to use the output from the cars_res to know what the values were and these were in the order of statistic, blank, p-value, estimate etc, whilst the car_res had labelled columns with estimate, statistic, p value.

1. was wondering why the output is in different orders and not
   labelled with the second approach?
2. can I use one of the apply functions in place of the above function?

Any comments would be appreciated.

Comment: You wrote "I would like to convert this into a function, as I would like to try using the future package".  I'd like to clarify that your existing `foreach()` call will parallelize via the future framework if you use `doFuture::registerDoFuture()`. See <https://dofuture.futureverse.org/> for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without parallelization you can try `RcppAlgos::comboGeneral` first, which works very similar to `combn` but is implemented in C++ and therefore may be faster (it also has a `Parallel=` option, **however** it is ignored when `FUN` is used). Moreover I don't load `broom` and `dplyr`.

```
res <- RcppAlgos::comboGeneral(names(mtcars), 2, FUN=\(x) {
  data.frame(cor.test(mtcars[, x[1]], mtcars[, x[2]], method="spearman")[c(4, 1, 3, 7, 6)], t(x))
}, Parallel=TRUE, nThreads=7) |> do.call(what=rbind) |> `rownames<-`(NULL)

head(res)
#     estimate statistic      p.value                          method alternative  X1   X2
# 1 -0.9108013 10425.332 4.690287e-13 Spearman's rank correlation rho   two.sided mpg  cyl
# 2 -0.9088824 10414.862 6.370336e-13 Spearman's rank correlation rho   two.sided mpg disp
# 3 -0.8946646 10337.290 5.085969e-12 Spearman's rank correlation rho   two.sided mpg   hp
# 4  0.6514555  1901.659 5.381347e-05 Spearman's rank correlation rho   two.sided mpg drat
# 5 -0.8864220 10292.319 1.487595e-11 Spearman's rank correlation rho   two.sided mpg   wt
# 6  0.4669358  2908.399 7.055765e-03 Spearman's rank correlation rho   two.sided mpg qsec
```

**Alternatively,** if you're on Linux (or Mac, but not tested), you could use `parallel::mclapply`, which works like `lapply` but with multiple cores, and use `combn` beforehand. This gives you the freedom to choose an arbitrary subset of combinations.

```
ncomb <- as.data.frame(combn(names(mtcars), 2))

parallel::mclapply(ncomb[, c(1:2, 11:12)], \(x) {
  data.frame(cor.test(mtcars[, x[1]], mtcars[, x[2]], method="spearman")[c(4, 1, 3, 7, 6)], t(x)) 
}, mc.cores=7) |> do.call(what=rbind) |> `rownames<-`(NULL)
#     estimate  statistic      p.value                          method alternative  X1   X2
# 1 -0.9108013 10425.3320 4.690287e-13 Spearman's rank correlation rho   two.sided mpg  cyl
# 2 -0.9088824 10414.8622 6.370336e-13 Spearman's rank correlation rho   two.sided mpg disp
# 3  0.9276516   394.7330 2.275443e-14 Spearman's rank correlation rho   two.sided cyl disp
# 4  0.9017909   535.8287 1.867686e-12 Spearman's rank correlation rho   two.sided cyl   hp
```

On Windows you can use `parallel::parLapply`.

```
library(parallel)

CL <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1)
clusterExport(CL, c('ncomb', 'mtcars'))  ## `mtcars` symbolizes you data

parLapply(CL, ncomb[, c(1:2, 11:12)], \(x) {
  data.frame(cor.test(mtcars[, x[1]], mtcars[, x[2]], method="spearman")[c(4, 1, 3, 7, 6)], t(x)) 
}) |> do.call(what=rbind) |> `rownames<-`(NULL)

stopCluster(CL)
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17201586/6574038) for more details on the use of `parLapply` vs `mclapply`.

Comment: thank you for this - was wondering would this allow me to run say res, res2 etc in parallel, like future would,  if I wanted to obtain the correlation matrix for different subsets of the full dataset (4 in total) or would I need to wait until each one completed before running the next one?

Comment: @aim6789 See update, hope I understood correctly.

Comment: `RcppAlgos` author here. When `FUN` is utilized the arguments: `Parallel` and `nThreads` are ignored and execution proceeds serially. I'll spare the details, but at a high level, the implementation of the `FUN` feature is very similar to `vapply|lapply` and isn't thread safe. However, one can still generated results in parallel by making use of `lower` and `upper` (E.g. [Generating Results Beyond `.Machine$integer.max`](https://jwood000.github.io/RcppAlgos/articles/GeneralCombinatorics.html#generating-results-beyond--machineinteger-max))

Comment: I forgot to mention, you can view other cases where the parallel arguments are ignored by looking at the **Note** section of `?comboGeneral`. I've been contemplating adding some sort of message or warning in cases like this.

Comment: @JosephWood Thanks very much for your comments (and thx for this great package BTW), it actually felt faster at first, so that was definitely a placebo effect! But it's also only a small task. Getting a warning would be really useful in case someone forgets to read the documentation. If you can improve the `comboGeneral` solution please feel free to edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can easily use your existing `foreach()` construct for parallelizing via the future framework.  Just add [`doFuture::registerDoFuture()`](https://dofuture.futureverse.org/) and pick your parallel backend with `plan()`, e.g.

```r
library(foreach)
doFuture::registerDoFuture() ## make %dopar% use futureverse
plan(multisession)           ## parallel background workers

combo_cars <- data.frame(t(combn(names(mtcars),2)))

cars_res <- foreach(i=1:nrow(combo_cars), .combine=rbind, .packages=c("magrittr", "dplyr")) %dopar% {
  broom::tidy(cor.test(mtcars[, combo_cars[i,1]],
                       mtcars[,combo_cars[i,2]],
                       method = "spearman")) %>% 
  mutate(Var1=combo_cars[i,1], Var2=combo_cars[i,2])
}
```

Second, analogously to jay.sf's solutions, you can use **[future.apply](https://future.apply.futureverse.org/)** as:

```r
library(future.apply)
plan(multisession)

ncomb <- as.data.frame(combn(names(mtcars), 2))

res <- future_lapply(ncomb[, c(1:2, 11:12)], \(x) {
  data.frame(cor.test(mtcars[, x[1]], mtcars[, x[2]], method="spearman")[c(4, 1, 3, 7, 6)], t(x)) 
}) |> do.call(what=rbind) |> `rownames<-`(NULL)
```

`plan(multisession)` corresponds uses a PSOCK cluster of the **parallel** package, similarly to `parallel::makeCluster()`.  If you switch to`plan(multicore)`, the parallelization will be done via forked processing using the same framework as `parallel::mclapply()`.

The advantage of using **futureverse** compared to `parallel::mclapply()` and `parallel::parLapply()` is that you get better error handling, and messages and warnings are relayed.  For example, if you run the above, you'll get:

```
Warning messages:
1: In cor.test.default(mtcars[, x[1]], mtcars[, x[2]], method = "spearman") :
  Cannot compute exact p-value with ties
2: In cor.test.default(mtcars[, x[1]], mtcars[, x[2]], method = "spearman") :
  Cannot compute exact p-value with ties
3: In cor.test.default(mtcars[, x[1]], mtcars[, x[2]], method = "spearman") :
  Cannot compute exact p-value with ties
4: In cor.test.default(mtcars[, x[1]], mtcars[, x[2]], method = "spearman") :
  Cannot compute exact p-value with ties
```

Note that those warnings are completely muffled by other parallelization frameworks in R.